# Reusable / Shared View not showing in Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I created a Framework so that I can reuse views across several projects. I used [this](https://www.unicorn-it.de/developing-reusable-views-in-a-swift-framework/) link to create the Framework. I can reference it in a project and the shared views do show in the storyboard. However, when I run it in the simulator, the sharable views are white. Attached are screen shots of what I'm experiencing. I'm using swift 3.0 and xcode 8.2.1.

[image: Simulator]

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: there are errors in the console, can you paste them out here?

Comment: It was referencing a previous error that I corrected (one of the views has an Imageview and the image link was broken since I created the framework from a previous existing project).

Comment: Have you tried running in other simulators?

Comment: The same occurs on different simulators and on a real/physical device (tested on a iPhone 6s).

Answer (score 0):

In the **Identity Inspector** of the View, change the **module** of your class to the name of your framework.

[image: module]

References to custom classes need to have both the class name and module set in the Identity Inspector when using Storyboards. At the time when the custom class is set, your that class was in the app’s module, but now it’s in the framework.

Comment: This was already set. If this wasn't set properly, the storyboard would be white also but as you can see my storyboard shows the custom view as its suppose to be.